# Get modified files in Github actions

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I have 2 Github Actions workflows in my repository and one of the steps requires getting all the files that have been modified (except deleted files) in a PR. I use this in the first one:

```
on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]


jobs:
  get_files:
    name: run_on_pr
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@master
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Modified files
        run: |
          git fetch origin main:main
          git diff --name-only --diff-filter=d main~ main
```

This one works okay and I am able to get a list of all the files that have been modified. However, in the second workflow, which is supposed to run when the PR is merged, this does not work.

```
on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]


jobs:
  get_files:
    name: run_when_pr_is_merged
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@master
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Modified files
        run: |
          git fetch origin main:main
          git diff --name-only --diff-filter=d main~ main
```

I get the error
`fatal: refusing to fetch into branch 'refs/heads/main' checked out at '/home/runner/....'`. I think the error is coming from the `git fetch origin main:main` as the workflow is running off the `main` branch and I am trying to do a fetch in there. I have removed that but still didn't get the list I needed. Any help or better way to get the list of modified files in a PR in both workflows?

Comment: What does the `git diff` command returns in the second workflow if you remove the `git fetch` command?

Comment: When I do this, it gives me modified files that are weren't even modified in the branch or a part of this PR. The `git fetch` filters this to only return the ones that were modified in the PR

Comment: Is it the same behavior if you remove the `fetch-depth: 0` from the `actions/checkout` step?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's a bit more complicated than this.

For PR's GitHub `action/checkout` is created a detached head which is simulating a merge of the PR into the target branch. You can see it in the logs of the checkout action itself. You can alter this behavior by using a different ref, but I don't recommend it - it's actually making things easier, especially for forked PRs.

To get a list of changed files in PR, you just have to checkout with fetch-depth: 2 to get previous commits and then get files modified by a merge:

```
- name: Checkout
  uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
     fetch-depth: 2
- name: Get changes
  run: git diff --name-only -r HEAD^1 HEAD
```

For `push` events, it's also a bit more complicated as you can have multiple commits in single push, so here you have to fetch-depth: 0 and then use the GitHub context values to figure out the difference for the `push`:

```
- name: Checkout
  uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
     fetch-depth: 0
- name: Get changes
  run: git diff --name-only ${{ github.event.before }} ${{ github.event.after }}
```

If you want a single workflow to handle both, you can do something like this:

```
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
      fetch-depth: ${{ github.event_name == 'pull_request' && 2 || 0 }}
- name: Get changed files
  id: changed-files
  run: |
      if ${{ github.event_name == 'pull_request' }}; then
          echo "changed_files=$(git diff --name-only -r HEAD^1 HEAD | xargs)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
      else
          echo "changed_files=$(git diff --name-only ${{ github.event.before }} ${{ github.event.after }} | xargs)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
      fi
- name: List changed files
  run: |
      for file in ${{ steps.changed-files.outputs.changed_files }}; do
          echo "$file was changed"
      done
```

Comment: Does the -r do anything for `git diff`? I couldn't find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the necessary fetch-depth was my problem. What if a push event has 15 commits? The [`github.event` object](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context:%7E:text=github.event,object) is the key.

> The full event webhook payload. You can access individual properties of the event using this context. This object is identical to the webhook payload of the event that triggered the workflow run, and is different for each event. The webhooks for each GitHub Actions event is linked in "[Events that trigger workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows)." For example, for a workflow run triggered by the [`push` event](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#push), this object contains the contents of the [push webhook payload](https://docs.github.com/en/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#push).

So for a `push` event, you should be able to build the list by pulling the `modified` array (and maybe the `added` array, too) out of each element of the `github.event.commits` array. I have a repo where this will apply and I'll test it soon and update here exactly how I did it.

For a `pull_request` event, it's less clear how this could be done differently. The best lead I'm seeing off the bat is `github.event.pull_request.commits_url`, but documentation on what that actually contains is light. I'll see if I can experiment a bit with this while I'm working on the `push` event and update here.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the accepted answer with a slightly simpler (though maybe a little more naive) approach, here's what's working quite well for me and my team...

```yaml
name: ...
on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]
jobs:
  run:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }}
          fetch-depth: 0
      - uses: actions/github-script@v6
        with:
          script: |
            const { execSync } = require('child_process')
            const { commits } = context.payload.pull_request
            const rawFiles = execSync(`git diff --name-only HEAD HEAD~${commits}`).toString()
            const files = rawFiles.split('\n').filter(Boolean)

            console.log(files)
```

The `ref` and `fetch-depth` customize the `checkout` action such that it pulls enough git info and operates off the latest commit on your branch. You should see an array of your changed `files` spit out in the action log and be able to do with them whatever you'd like. You may not even need the `github-script` action, I'm just using that for something else.

The `pull_request` context does have something like `changed_files` at the time of writing but it only provides a count unfortunately. Read more about the `checkout` options [here](https://github.com/actions/checkout).