# Github Action to check if file has changed

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I would like to have a Github action that checks if a file has changed, being this way mandatory to change the content of one file (changelog in my case) to pass the CI in a PR.

Comment: Did you try using the [paths](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-including-paths) subtype on a push trigger?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get modified files in Github actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74265821/get-modified-files-in-github-actions)